# Entry 'FlatFile TraceListener' has already been added error

Tags: xml

I am using logging in my project to trace some error log Details. This is my Root Web.config setting.

```
<add fileName="C:\NET20Root\EIGRoot\Wedding\Tracing\WeddingEIG.Weddings.Trace.log" header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="FlatFile TraceListener"/>
<add fileName="C:\NET20Root\EIGRoot\Household\Tracing\HouseholdEIG.Household.Trace.log" header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="FlatFile TraceListener"/>
```

and facing this error

**The entry 'FlatFile TraceListener' has already been added.**

Can some one please help me on this what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

What this error message is telling you is that there should be single child in parent tag
e.g you can add only one `FlatFile TraceListener`.

Configuration is just a way of telling program what settings it should use, and program must support dealing with array of listeners which at the moment I assume it does not.

Comment: I have to trace logging for two projects basically. How can I get through it.? Is there any alternate way of doing this?

Comment: @RishiVedpathi I would look in logger's that you are using documentation, you might need to set it per project.

Comment: I am using using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.